# $p$ and $q$ are primes. Prove $\forall n,k\in \mathbb N, (p^n\mid q^k⇒p=q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble answering this question, can anyone help explain a full solution of this problem? I will be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p^n | q^k$, then so does $p$ (since $p \, | \, p^n$),
$$
p \, | \,  q^k.
$$
So since $p$ is prime, it is one of the prime divisors of $q^n$. But the only prime divisor of $q^k$ is $q$, since $q$ is prime. Hence $p = q$.

Comment: Worth *explicit* mention is that the proof implicitly uses the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, i.e. the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations.